# Listen to all events on Flutter's TabController

Tags: flutter, tabs

If you want to know when the user changed the tab page you can use the regular `TabController.addListener()` method. But what about knowing all the user events, like, for example, the user started to scroll to another page?

I need to know when the user starts scrolling to a new page. Knowing that the user already scrolled to a new page is too late.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

Adding a listener to the `tabController` will only listen to the tab index change but to listen to the changing value (the index in double) you can add the listener to the animation of the `tabController`.

Here a full code, I am using `flutter_hooks` to create the `tabController`.

```
class TestTabListener extends HookWidget {
  const TestTabListener();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tabController = useTabController(initialLength: 3);

    tabController.animation!.addListener(() {
      if (tabController.animation!.value != tabController.index) {
        {
          //code
          print("runing");
        }
      }
    });

    return Scaffold(
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: tabController,
        children: pages,
      ),
    );
  }

  static final pages = [
    Container(color: Colors.red),
    Container(color: Colors.black),
    Container(color: Colors.blue),
  ];
}
```

Be careful using a function here because it will be called multiple times, you might add condition.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @7mada! But that's exactly the issue I'm facing. The function is only called when the page animation ends. Never in between. So if I move from tab 0 to 1 and then to 2, the function is only called twice.

Just to clarify, which kind of TabController are you using? How are you instantiating it? Just `tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);`?

Comment: By the way, `index` is an `int` and `animation` is an `Animation`. There are never going to be equal.

Comment: Sorry the answer wasn't test, I will update it.

Comment: Oh! That subtle change changes everything, haha! I'll give it a try. Thanks a lot, @7mada :·)

Comment: I typed my first answer from my phone and didn't test it , I hope now it works fine dude :).

Answer (score 0):

simple detection will be like below:

```
tabBarController =
    TabController(length: 5, initialIndex: pageNumber, vsync: this);
tabBarController.addListener(() {
  changePage(tabBarController.index);
});
```